# SQL to label rows in a table

Tags: sql, azure-databricks

I have this table t1 in databrick as below

[image]

Can help me to write a query to get this result:

[image]

sort the table data by row_num by descending first, then look at "Event Label" column, if "Event Label" is "Hire" then Result is 0, the result is 0 for the next rows until encountering the "Event label" as "Rehire", then the result is increased by 1 to be 1, and 1 for the following rows until encountering the "Event label" as "Rehire", then the result is increased by 1 again to be 2, and so on, repeating the same process.

I tried some way but no luck.

Comment: Seems you have to use more than SQL to achieve this. Also, please tag the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Hi Ser, I'm using databrick

Comment: If your 'Event Label' column value is again 'Hire', then the Result should be 0 or decremented by 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure SQL, a cumulative sum would be sufficient...

```
SELECT
  *,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN [event label] = 'Rehire' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  )
  OVER (
    PARTITION BY user_id
        ORDER BY row_id
  )
    AS Result
FROM
  t1
```